# Enable a button on slider values

Tags: wpf

I have three sliders and one button. The button has a click event.

What I want is when the sum of three slider values is greater than 0, than enable this button.

The code is simple, I guess:

```
int total = slider1.Value + slider2.Value + slider3.Value;
if total > 0
   btnStart.Enable = true;
else
   btnStart.Enable = false;
```

The question is I don't know where should I place the code. If I put it in slider events, there are three. It is duplicated.

However if we have many many sliders, is the method foolish?

Comment: you can assign same event handler method to all 3 sliders `ValueChanged` event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a `ValueChanged` event and attach it on your three sliders e.g:

```
private void Slider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
   btnStart.IsEnabled = (slider1.Value > 0 && slider2.Value > 0 && slider3.Value > 0);
}
```

XAML would look like this:

```
<Slider x:Name="slider1" ValueChanged="Slider_ValueChanged"/>
<Slider x:Name="slider2" ValueChanged="Slider_ValueChanged"/>
<Slider x:Name="slider3" ValueChanged="Slider_ValueChanged"/>
```

Example for your button:

```
<Button x:Name="btnStart" IsEnabled="False">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False"/>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Comment: Can we also make the appearance of the button different? So I can see the difference when dragging the sliders..

Comment: In that case, you should apply a `Style` to your button whose appearance changes when the `IsEnabled` property changes.

Comment: It works out. Thanks. One follow up question, the initial color is green. By dragging any slide, the color is red then. If we drag it back to the 0, it is still red, I want it is green.

Comment: What do you mean? If all values are 0, the button must be green?

Comment: Yes, if you could not do it, that is fine.

Comment: Copy the entire button. Here you go ;-)